# Error al ejecutar seeder, laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel-5

Hoy me encuentro ejecutando un Seeder, con lo cual pretendo llenar algunas tablas que anteriormente se crearon en la migracion, pero obtengo el siguiente error.

```html
 SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'newsiete.alcaldes' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `alcaldes` (`alcalde_candidato`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (AlcaldeUno, 2019-01-30 13:07:54, 2019-01-30 13:07:54))
```

El modelo que tengo es este.

```html
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Alcalde extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['alcalde_candidato',];


      public function usuarios()
     {

       return $this->hasMany(Usuarios::class);

     }
}
```

y el seeder

```html
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class Alcalde_Seeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
          \App\Alcalde::create([
            'alcalde_candidato' => 'AlcaldeUno',
        ]);


       \App\Alcalde::create([
            'alcalde_candidato' => 'AlcaldeDos',
        ]);


        \App\Alcalde::create([
            'alcalde_candidato' => 'AlcaldeTres',
        ]);


        \App\Alcalde::create([
            'alcalde_candidato' => 'AlcaldeCuatro',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Por que razon el error dice que mi tabla tiene una s, como si estuviera en plural, cuando en realidad no lo esta.

Comment: Has probado agregando el atributo `$table` a tu Model? `protected $table = 'alcaldes';`

Comment: no!, voy a mirar

Comment: vale agrégalo y comentas. Iría antes o después de `protected $fillable`

Comment: Funciono!, por que paso esto? acaso es por que laravel solo maneja idioma ingles en mi caso? en protected excluye entonces ese comportamiento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el Model agregar el atributo protegido Tabla, que indicara a Eloquent que usara esa tabla y no buscara otra según la convención de Modelos de Eloquent.

`protected $table = 'alcaldes';`

```
class Alcalde extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'alcaldes';
  protected $fillable = ['alcalde_candidato',];


  public function usuarios()
    {

     return $this->hasMany(Usuarios::class);

    }
}
```

Eloquent asumirá que el modelo `Flight` almacena registros en la tabla `flights`. Para el ejemplo que esta en la documentación, si la convención de Modelos de Laravel usa el idioma ingles, pero puede especificar una tabla personalizada definiendo la propiedad `table` en su modelo.

Mas detalles de la convención para [Model de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions)

Comment: Cesar, es muy usted amable, muchas gracias por la ayuda, todo muy claro.